# Find out if email is in "sent" folder

Tags: google-apps-script

For a given Gmail message I want to find out if the email is in "sent" folder.

For the other folders there are classes
- isDraft()
- isInInbox()
- isInTrash()

But I cannot find a class like "isInSent()".

How can I find out from google-apps-script if an email is in the "sent" folder?

Answer (score 1):

The `.getFrom()` will always be you.

And if you want to have the `isInSent()` class, you could write something in the lines of:

```
function isInSent(GmailMessageId) {
  return GmailApp.getMessageById(GmailMessageId).getFrom().indexOf(Session.getActiveUser()) != -1
}
```

This code returns `true` if the one who's running the script is the one who sent the checked email, `false` otherwise.

Comment: This is closer than the other answer, but I would recommend adding a check for "isDraft", because the above is going to return true for messages that have been started but not sent yet.

Answer (score -1):

In the end I came to the following code that works for me. It's based on a workaround:

If the Email is not in any of the other folders, then it mus be in "sent"-folder

```
var messageById = GmailApp.getMessageById(message_id);

    //Classify message by folder in gmail
    if (messageById.isDraft()==true) {
      is_draft_email = "1";
    } else {
      is_draft_email = "0";
    }

    //isInInbox()?
    if (messageById.isInInbox()==true) {
      is_inbox_email = "1";
    } else {
      is_inbox_email = "0";
    }

    //isInTrash()?
    if (messageById.isInTrash()==true) {
      var is_in_trash_email = "1";
      } else {
        var is_in_trash_email = "0";
        }

    //isInChats()
    if (messageById.isInChats()==true) {
      var is_in_chats_email = "1";
      } else {
        var is_in_chats_email = "0";
        }

    //Is it a sent message?
    //There is no simple method known to check this. See posting on Stackoverflow:
    //Workaround: If Email is not in any of the other folders, then it mus be in "sent"-folder
    if ((is_draft_email == "0") && (is_inbox_email == "0") && (is_in_trash_email == "0") && (is_in_chats_email == "0")) {
      is_sent_email = "1";
    } else
    {is_sent_email = "0"}
```

Comment: You can have an e-mail that's not in inbox, drafts, trash or chats and still not be in the sent mailbox. You can remove the inbox label from a message without deleting it, and it would be considered 'sent' according to your code.